# Count submatrices with all ones

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am given a N*M Grid of 0s ans 1s.I need to find number of those submatrices of size A*B which have all 1s inside them.

Like suppose i have a grid of 2*6

The Grid is :

0 1 1 1 1 0

0 1 1 1 1 1

Now if say i want to find submatrices of size 2*3

Then here answer is 2.

Comment: I don't understand why 2 (I find 3). Can you explain ?

Comment: @hivert The one starting at (0,1) and the one starting at (0,2). Which is the third one? And OP, please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @hivert how three?Their are only two .One at start index (1,2) and other at starting index (1,3)

Comment: @Carsten I know to find largest submatrix with all 1s using largest area under histogram.Can it be modified for this question?

Comment: Maybe. I just wanna see what you've tried so far. Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: Are there any particular requirements, e.g. concerning the running time? So far, the problem sounds trivial: `for each cell(x,y) { if (thereIsASubmatrixAt(x,y)) count++; }`. BTW: Some programming language tag might also be interesting.

Comment: @Carsten i cant paste such a big code here

Comment: Any requirements on the sizes of the matrixes?  If we are talking about 1 billion x 1 billion then this is a disk access optimization problem.

Comment: @brianbeuning No n,m can be at max 1000 .So no need for disk access optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** The following hints assume that by "submatrix" you meant "the intersection of a *contiguous* subset of rows and a *contiguous* subset of columns".  (Usually a submatrix is allowed to skip rows and columns.)

I believe this is a homework question, so I'll just provide a hint instead of a full answer.

Suppose there was a way to efficiently calculate, for each cell (i, j), whether it was the rightmost cell of a run of at least m 1s in a row.  How would that help?

Another hint: any given cell (i, j) is either the bottom-rightmost corner of some N*M grid of 1s, or it isn't.